# Streamparse wordcount example

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, streamparse

I have been wanting to use Apache Storm to stream from Kafka. I am more comfortable with Python, so I decided to use streamparse (https://github.com/Parsely/streamparse). The word count example is the introductory example. I have been trying to get it to work on my local machine. I have the following version of JDK, lein and storm installed:

```
Leiningen 2.6.1 on Java 1.8.0_73 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

I run the following steps after following streamparse:

```
sparse quick start wordcount
cd wordcount
sparse run
```

I get the following error:

```
Retrieving org/apache/storm/storm-core/0.10.1/storm-core-0.10.1.pom from central
Retrieving org/apache/storm/storm/0.10.1/storm-0.10.1.pom from central
Retrieving org/apache/storm/storm-core/0.10.1/storm-core-0.10.1.jar from central
Could not transfer artifact com.parsely:streamparse:pom:0.0.4-SNAPSHOT from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Could not transfer artifact clojure-complete:clojure-complete:pom:0.2.4 from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.
```

My project.clj file reads like this :

```
    (defproject wordcount "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
      :source-paths ["topologies"]
      :resource-paths ["_resources"]
      :target-path "_build"
      :min-lein-version "2.6.1"
      :jvm-opts ["-client"]
      :dependencies  [[org.apache.storm/storm-core "0.10.1"]
                  [com.parsely/streamparse "0.0.4-SNAPSHOT"]
                  ]
      :jar-exclusions     [#"log4j\.properties" #"backtype" #"trident" #"META-INF" #"meta-inf" #"\.yaml"]
      :uberjar-exclusions [#"log4j\.properties" #"backtype" #"trident" #"META-INF" #"meta-inf" #"\.yaml"]
  )
```

So, my lein and storm core versions are set correctly. I'm not sure where I am going wrong . Could somebody help me out?

-Thanks

Answer (score 32):

This is because Java doesn't recognize the root certificate authority (CA) SSL certificate of https://clojars.org/repo.

Solution is to add that certificate to Java `cacerts` file so that it got permanently accepted.

Steps:

1. Open https://clojars.org in Chrome
2. In address bar, click on the **lock icon**
3. Click on **Connection is secure**
4. Click on **Certificate is valid**
5. Go to the **Details** tab
6. In the **Certificate Hierarchy** box, the root certificate is the one, you need to work with
7. Export this root certificate via the `mmc` tool:

   1. Call the `mmc` tool via console
   2. Click **File** -> **Add/Remove Snap-In...**, select **Certificates - Current User**, press **OK**
   3. In **Certificates - Current User** -> **Trusted Root Certification Authorities** -> **Certificates**, find your root certificate from the step #6, double click on it
   4. Go to **Details** tab
   5. Click on **Copy to File...**
   6. Follow the wizard, select **DER encoded binary X.509 (.CER)** and export it
8. In the console, run the JRE/JDK **keytool.exe** from the **bin** folder:

```bash
keytool -importcert –noprompt -file %PATH_TO_EXPORTED_CERTIFICATE% -keystore %PATH_TO_SAVE_CACERTS% -alias "%CACERTS_ALIAS%"
```

9. In Eclipse folder, open **eclipse.ini**
10. Below the line `-vmargs`, adjust the values of `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType`, which define the path to the exported `CACERTS`
11. Restart Eclipse

Comment: Final step restart eclipse :)

Comment: when copy-pasting the keytool command, the dashes are not copied correctly. You should replace `–` with `-`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using debian or ubuntu you can execute:

```
$ sudo update-ca-certificates -f
```