# Rocket chip generator build error: sbt proxy

Tags: scala, sbt, riscv, rocket

I am trying to download Rocket chip generator and build a
Rocket core RTL using the generator. The guidance is relatively
simple, as in the following link. I only need to type a several
lines of commands.
https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocket-chip

However, when I finally try to generate the verilog files by
the command 'make verilog' after all configurations, I get stuck
to the following error which pretty much seems to be related to 
sbt dependencies.

> [info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-ghpages;0.5.3 ... [error] Server
>   access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path
>   building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target url=~ [error] Server
>   access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path
>   building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target url=~[error] Server
>   access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path
>   building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target url=https:~

......................

> [error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:
>   com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-ghpages;0.5.3: not found [error] unresolved
>   dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-site;0.8.1: not found [error]
>   unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-buildinfo;0.5.0: not found

Note that, I replaced the URLs to '~' mark since I was unable to write
more than 2 links via this post, being a noob in stack overflow.

Indeed, I do not find the upper listed repo sites, not even on my 
web browser. Does anybody have any idea how to build the rocket chips?

Comment: The answer to exactly the problem described in your question can be found here: [SBT 0.13.11 cannot download dependencies behind a proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37440794/new-project-sbt-0-13-11-not-found-causing-problems-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: oh my god! i cant thank you enough. ive been wasting 2 whole days at work and at home to resolve this problem.