# How do I configure WebServiceTemplate to send soap request to Server under HTTPS?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, spring-ws, two-way

I have  configured keystore and trustore for the application .I have tried to consume web Service using WebService template over HTTPS here is my configuration

```
public GetCountryResponse find() throws MalformedURLException, GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    GetCountryRequest request = new GetCountryRequest();
    request.setName("Spain");
    SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();

    LayeredConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = null;
    try {
        sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(SSLContext.getDefault(),
                SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    }

    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\client.p12"));
    try {
        keyStore.load(instream, "password".toCharArray());
    } finally {
        instream.close();
    }

    // Trust own CA and all self-signed certs
    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, "password".toCharArray())
            // .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
            .build();
    // Allow TLSv1 protocol only
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new String[] { "TLSv1" }, null,
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER); // TODO
    HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setHostnameVerifier(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER) // TODO
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).addInterceptorFirst(new ContentRemover()).build();

    HttpComponentsMessageSender messageSender = new HttpComponentsMessageSender(httpclient);

    WebServiceMessageSender sender = messageSender;

    WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = getWebServiceTemplate();
    webServiceTemplate.setMessageSender(sender);

    GetCountryResponse response = (GetCountryResponse) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(
            "https://localhost:8443/ws/countries.wsdl", request,
            new SoapActionCallback("https://localhost:8443/ws/"));

    return response;
}
```

I get the following error

```
    %% Invalidated:  [Session-4, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384]
    http-nio-8444-exec-2, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
    http-nio-8444-exec-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
    http-nio-8444-exec-2, called closeSocket()
    http-nio-8444-exec-2, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    14:38:01.080 [http-nio-8444-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-1: Shutdown connection
    http-nio-8444-exec-2, called close()
    http-nio-8444-exec-2, called closeInternal(true)
    14:38:01.080 [http-nio-8444-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Connection discarded
    14:38:01.080 [http-nio-8444-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-1: Close connection
    14:38:01.080 [http-nio-8444-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 1][route: {s}->https://localhost:8443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
    14:38:01.080 [http-nio-8444-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public com.covenant.app.wsdl.GetCountryResponse com.covenant.app.controllers.DealController.findAllDeals()]: org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    14:38:01.080 [http-nio-8444-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Invoking @ExceptionHandler method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.covenant.app.controllers.DealController.errorHandler(java.lang.Exception)
    14:38:01 [http-nio-8444-exec-2] DealController - I/O error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:561)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
        at com.covenant.app.services.WeatherClient.find(WeatherClient.java:90)
        at com.covenant.app.controllers.DealController.findAllDeals(DealController.java:34)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1757)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1716)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:262)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:118)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:314)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:357)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:218)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:194)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:85)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsConnection.onSendAfterWrite(HttpComponentsConnection.java:121)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.send(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:48)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendRequest(WebServiceTemplate.java:658)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:606)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
        ... 41 more
    Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
        ... 65 more
    Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
        ... 71 more
    14:38:01.094 [http-nio-8444-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyAdviceChain - Invoking ResponseBodyAdvice chain for body=I/O error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    14:38:01.094 [http-nio-8444-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyAdviceChain - After ResponseBodyAdvice chain body=I/O error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    http-nio-8444-exec-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 669
    14:38:01.096 [http-nio-8444-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Written [I/O error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target] as "text/html" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@65423e86]
    14:38:01.096 [http-nio-8444-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
    14:38:01.096 [http-nio-8444-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
    http-nio-8444-exec-2, called closeOutbound()
    http-nio-8444-exec-2, closeOutboundInternal()
    http-nio-8444-exec-2, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
    http-nio-8444-exec-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 26
    http-nio-8444-exec-4, called closeOutbound()
    http-nio-8444-exec-4, closeOutboundInternal()
```

In the browser I get the following error

```
I/O error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building   failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I searched in the Internet for Solution so I tried using

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new String[] { "TLSv1" }, null,
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER); // TODO
    HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setHostnameVerifier(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER) // TODO
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();

    HttpComponentsMessageSender messageSender = new HttpComponentsMessageSender(httpclient);

    WebServiceMessageSender sender = messageSender;

    WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = getWebServiceTemplate();
    webServiceTemplate.setMessageSender(sender);
```

But Then i get the following exception

```
    trustStore is: C:\trustore.jks
    trustStore type is : jks
    trustStore provider is : 
    init truststore
    adding as trusted cert:
      Subject: EMAILADDRESS=briantauro7@gmail.com, CN=localhost, OU=localhost, O=ITCOVENANT, L=Coimbatore, ST=Tamil Badu, C=IN
      Issuer:  EMAILADDRESS=briantauro7@gmail.com, CN=localhost, OU=localhost, O=ITCOVENANT, L=Coimbatore, ST=Tamil Badu, C=IN
      Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x9f141ecadb1b5892
      Valid from Mon Jun 06 22:09:30 IST 2016 until Tue Jun 06 22:09:30 IST 2017

    trigger seeding of SecureRandom
    done seeding SecureRandom
    00:00:38.964 [http-nio-8444-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate - Opening [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsConnection@47cea62b] to [https://localhost:8443/ws/countries.wsdl]
    00:00:39.032 [http-nio-8444-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent - Sent request [SaajSoapMessage {http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service}getCountryRequest]
    00:00:39.085 [http-nio-8444-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public com.covenant.app.wsdl.GetCountryResponse com.covenant.app.controllers.DealController.findAllDeals() throws java.net.MalformedURLException,java.security.GeneralSecurityException,java.io.IOException]: org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: null; nested exception is org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    00:00:39.089 [http-nio-8444-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Invoking @ExceptionHandler method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.covenant.app.controllers.DealController.errorHandler(java.lang.Exception)
    00:00:39 [http-nio-8444-exec-2] DealController - I/O error: null; nested exception is org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: null; nested exception is org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:561)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
        at com.covenant.app.services.WeatherClient.find(WeatherClient.java:98)
        at com.covenant.app.controllers.DealController.findAllDeals(DealController.java:37)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1757)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1716)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:188)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsConnection.onSendAfterWrite(HttpComponentsConnection.java:121)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.send(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:48)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendRequest(WebServiceTemplate.java:658)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:606)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
        ... 41 more
    Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Content-Length header already present
        at org.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent.process(RequestContent.java:96)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:132)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:192)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:85)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
        ... 49 more
    00:00:39.111 [http-nio-8444-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyAdviceChain - Invoking ResponseBodyAdvice chain for body=I/O error: null; nested exception is org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    00:00:39.111 [http-nio-8444-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyAdviceChain - After ResponseBodyAdvice chain body=I/O error: null; nested exception is org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    http-nio-8444-exec-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 303
    00:00:39.115 [http-nio-8444-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Written [I/O error: null; nested exception is org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException] as "text/html" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@4ec86e91]
    00:00:39.115 [http-nio-8444-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
    00:00:39.115 [http-nio-8444-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
    http-nio-8444-exec-2, called closeOutbound()
    http-nio-8444-exec-2, closeOutboundInternal()
    http-nio-8444-exec-2, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
    http-nio-8444-exec-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 26
    http-nio-8444-exec-5, called closeOutbound()
    http-nio-8444-exec-5, closeOutboundInternal()
    http-nio-8444-exec-5, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
    http-nio-8444-exec-5, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 26
    http-nio-8444-exec-4, called closeOutbound()
    http-nio-8444-exec-4, closeOutboundInternal()
    http-nio-8444-exec-4, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
    http-nio-8444-exec-4, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 26
    http-nio-8444-exec-9, called closeOutbound()
    http-nio-8444-exec-9, closeOutboundInternal()
    http-nio-8444-exec-9, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
    http-nio-8444-exec-9, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 26
```

If i add this code along with

```
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
              .setHostnameVerifier(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER) //   TODO
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).addInterceptorFirst(new  ContentRemover()).build();
```

Content Remover Class:

```
public  class ContentRemover implements HttpRequestInterceptor{

@Override
public void process(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) 
        throws HttpException, IOException {

    if (request instanceof HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) {
        System.out.println("wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww");
        if (request.containsHeader(HTTP.TRANSFER_ENCODING)) {
            request.removeHeaders(HTTP.TRANSFER_ENCODING);
        }
        if (request.containsHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_LEN)) {
            request.removeHeaders(HTTP.CONTENT_LEN);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Then again I get the same error that is

```
 I/O error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building   failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Please kindly help .If any link or sample code kindly update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution I just had to specify the keystore and trustore as vm arguments while running tomcat 7 it started working

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="C:\keystore.jks"
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\trustore.jks"
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
-Djavax.net.debug=SSL
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps for permanent solution

Step 1

1. Open your https link in chrome browser.
2. click on lock symbol just left side of your url at address bar.
3. Click on Details >> view certificate
4. Click on top most certificate from hierarchy.
5. Drag and drop that rectangular certificate image to desktop.

Step 2
Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37411410/1802348) link to save your certificate which is at desktop right now into cacert file.

Step 3
restart your IDE

Your problem is resolved now!

Comment: I have added the certificate to cacert file but still I get the same error

Comment: make sure that it is the same jre cacerts file which this app is using! many times multiple jre may exists! put certificate in every cacerts file.if still your problem not resolved please put all the details here so I can figure it out possible solution.

Comment: I have added the certificate to both jdk and jre still it gives me the same error