# Using gerrit rest api for Jenkins gerrit trigger

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

i want to enable Rest API for our gerrit tigger jenkins plugin.

So whenever i give the http username/password in the rest api enablement section of the gerrit tigger plugin. i get the following exception

```
Connection error : sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The password i took is from our gerrit installation's -> settings-> http password UI. I am not aware of the internal of our git/gerrit server installation and its configurations

my ssh connection for normal git+gerrit operations works fine.

Probably i am missing something very simple.

**EDIT**
Jenkins version : 2.7

Gerrit version : 2.12.2-49-g70b6923

Gerrit trigger plugin: 2.20.0

Regards,

Saurav

Comment: Which versions are you using? I tested with Jenkins 1.625.1, Gerrit Trigger 2.16.0, Gerrit 2.12.2 and it worked just fine.

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira...i have updated my post with the versions

Comment: Uhm... see if this link can help: https://myshittycode.com/2014/06/05/java-https-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when Java code try to connect through https using ssl certificate which is not listed in cacerts file of jre.

**Solution**

Step 1

Locate which JRE is responsible for this error.This is most important and but easy task!

Step 2

Open that HTTPS URL in CHROME BROWSER which gives this error most probably you have problem with https url of Gerrit server!

Step 3

-> After page load click on Lock like symbol located just left side of your       url.Click on it.

-> Click on details

-> Click on view certificate.

-> select TOP MOST CERTIFICATE in hierarchy and Drag and drop certificate image to desktop.

NOW YOU GOT CERTIFICATE.

Step 3

Detailed GUIDE how to install the certificate at cacerts file of jre is [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37411410/1802348) link

NOTE: Please post problem with details

Comment: Yes you are right...seems to be that my Jenkins JVM does not have the certificate with which gerrit  is configured in its trust store

Comment: Jenkins by default uses the jre which located under the jre sub-directory of your jenkins installation home ( %JENKINS_HOME ). change cacerts there update us all.