# maven repository sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:

Tags: java, maven

I have the fragment of pom.xml which tries to resolve the fitbit dependency:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <name>FitBit GitHub Repo</name>
            <id>fitbit4j</id>
            <url>https://nexus.vanntett.net/content/repositories/fitbit/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

I am getting the below error:

```
Failed to collect dependencies at com.fitbit:fitbit4j:jar:1.0.26: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.fitbit:fitbit4j:jar:1.0.26: Could not transfer artifact com.fitbit:fitbit4j:pom:1.0.26 from/to fitbit4j (https://nexus.vanntett.net/content/repositories/fitbit/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
```

I used these parameters in eclipse:
    -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -   Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true

which didn't work.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Try with regular non-secure url `http://nexus.....`...

Comment: Admin deleted my answer but since maven `3.9.0` , the ssl insecure switch is `-Daether.connector.https.securityMode=insecure` because they changed the transport away from `wagon`

Answer (score 6):

you need to enter your certificate inside java cacert file,Please make sure you are selecting root ca certicate not the last one in hierarchy.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37411410/1802348) link demonstrate it the best.

Step 1 : Download certificate
Step 2 : store inside cacert

That is it! your problem resolved.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your JDK does not have the CA root for the SSL certificate from the repository.

You can find a nice article [here](https://web.liferay.com/web/neil.griffin/blog/-/blogs/fixing-suncertpathbuilderexception-caused-by-maven-downloading-from-self-signed-repository) about downloading those certificates and adding it to your Java JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Check that run keytool -import.. command from jre which exists uder jdk.
like this.

1.Open cmd as admin...

1. go to path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin>
2. run bellow command.

   keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias certPen -file  D:\certificates\ca-cert.pem -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\security\cacerts"

and if u facing problem of file not found then set your all permission from
Right click on cacerts → choose properties → select Securit tab → Allow all permissions to all the Group and user names.