# Certification path error, non-resolvable parent pom

Tags: java, maven, certificate

My experience is almost exactly like the one who posted here [Certification path error when creating Maven project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50264870/certification-path-error-when-creating-maven-project-in-eclipse) except I haven't been able to fix my problem

I created a blank maven simple web project (in both eclipse and in vscode) but in my pom.xml at the parent tag, I get the following error.

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for
> com.group:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.3 failed
> to transfer from
> https://nexus.company.com/repository/maven-central-proxy/ during a
> previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and
> resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of
> e-maven-central-mirror has elapsed or updates are forced. Original
> error: Could not transfer artifact
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.3 from/to
> e-maven-central-mirror
> (https://nexus.company.com/repository/maven-central-proxy/): PKIX path
> building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target and
> 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM

In my settings.xml, I have my proxies, servers and mirrors tags set with the necessary information. (By my company's setup guide, this is all I should have but even with the proxy tags added, the non-resolvable parent POM error message stays)

```
<settings>   
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>e-maven-central-mirror</id>
      <username>username</username>
      <password>tokenpassword</password>
    </server>   
  </servers>   
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
     <!-- Comments about what are happening here -->
     <id>e-maven-central-mirror</id>
     <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
     <url>https://nexus.company.com/repository/maven-central-proxy/</url>   
    </mirror>   
  </mirrors> 
</settings>
```

I'm able to access the url with my id and my token password as normal. I've also gone through the trouble of adding the https://nexus.company.com/repository/maven-central-proxy certificate to both my %JAVA_HOME% (Jdk11) and %JRELOC% (Jre8) cacerts using the keytool. (I added to both as I wasn't sure which Java was the one being used)

I have spent a couple days on this and I'm not sure what it is that I'm doing wrong. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Edit: I have my env variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY set. Also saw that my nexus certificates were added to my JDK's keystore but not in the JRE's keystore if that's any useful informtation.

Comment: The message `PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid` implies that the certs are not there where they expected...furthermore the question is which JDK you are using and which Maven version do you use?

Comment: @khmarbaise I believe I was using the JDK 11 and embedded Maven for Eclipse. However, I'm primarily focusing on using VSCode so I used the Java Extension Pack and the Maven Extension as well. I do not have Maven installed on my machine so I cannot do any mvn commands if I wanted to. So I don't know what version of Maven I have. I also do not know how to check if VSCode looks for a JDK installed on my machine and if so, where is that setting.

Comment: Install the most recent version of Maven on your machine https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi and https://maven.apache.org/install.html Also have a working JDK correctly installed ...

Comment: Hi, I have installed Maven on my machine and my JDK seems correct. Here are my system env variables:
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk11.0.10_9
JRE64LOC = C:\Program Files\Java\jre8
JRELOC = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8