# Maven:unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, maven, ssl, proxy, eclipse-che

I get this error when I try to `mvn clean install` [che-orion-editor](https://github.com/eclipse/che-lib/tree/5.22.0/che-orion-editor)，the version is 5.22.0.

> Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-patch-plugin:1.1.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-patch-plugin:jar:1.1.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-patch-plugin:pom:1.1.1 from/to codenvy-public-repo (https://maven.codenvycorp.com/content/groups/public/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: `PKIX path building failed`: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: `unable to find valid certification path to requested target` -> [Help 1]

I have set the maven proxy correctly.

And I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911623/problems-using-maven-and-ssl-behind-proxy), it doen't work.

Comment: Did you also try to import the certificates according to the description in the 2nd answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911623/problems-using-maven-and-ssl-behind-proxy?

Comment: Thanks for your accurate answer, it work for me. I search the way to import the certificates in linux and succeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @weizenkeim hugo said, I search the way to import the certificates in linux.

just two steps:

- Get root certificate
- Get that certificate added to java cacerts file

and the link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398179/streamparse-wordcount-example/37411410#37411410)

Comment: In my case all I had to do was to update Java. The cert was signed by let's encrypt, not loaded in Java 8u80, but in Java8u191 which I upgraded to ... Something to check before manually adding :)