# Certificate error PKIX path building failed with gradle-processors-2.1.0.pom

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I an SpringBoot project using Gradle I am facing a issue when Gradle is downloading one dependency:

Error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve gradle.plugin.org.inferred:gradle-processors:2.1.0.


Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/gradle/plugin/org/inferred/gradle-processors/2.1.0/gradle-processors-2.1.0.pom'.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/gradle/plugin/org/inferred/gradle-processors/2.1.0/gradle-processors-2.1.0.pom'.

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I already tried the solution in this topic but it did not work: [Streamparse wordcount example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398179/streamparse-wordcount-example/37411410#37411410)

Do anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: I do not know why, but right now it is working after changes I have done following that thread.

Comment: After doing the keytool import, if it is still not working, kill any Gradle daemons that are running and try again.