# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building

Tags: java, spring-boot

sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

While trying to communicate with the other server .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear what caused the error you shared, so please clarify. It's also a good idea to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Looks like there's no valid certificate to the requested target..is the target server's certificate self-signed? If no, have you imported the certificate into the cacerts keystore?

Comment: install ssl cert to java cacerts. Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37411410/1802348) steps