# Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): PKIX path building failed

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, pkix

getting certifiate isssue while triggering API::

```
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|01|main|2022-11-22 05:56:38.677 UTC|TransportContext.java:361|Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (
"throwable" : {
  sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Verified the certificate and enabled the ssl debug log, but unable to get the root cause

Comment: you need to install yous ssl cert into java cacerts. refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37411410/1802348) answer.